# 'Object doesn't support this property or method' IE8 throwing jquery error

Tags: javascript, jquery

I get this error on the page when I load my website on IE8,

Message: Object doesn't support this property or method
Line: 1025
Char: 5
Code: 0
URI: http://www.domain-name.com/../default/js/jquery.wt-rotator.js

i.e this particular line of code

```
 $innerText.width(textWidth).html($p.html());
```

this is the complete block of code

```
var initTextData = function($item, padding)
 { 
 var $p = $item.find(">div:hidden"); var textWidth = getPosNumber(parseInt($p.css("width")) - padding, 300);
var textHeight = getPosNumber(parseInt($p.css("height")) - padding, 0); $innerText.width(textWidth).html($p.html());
if (textHeight < $innerText.height()) 
{ textHeight = $innerText.height(); 
}
 $item.data("textbox", {x:$p.css("left"), y:$p.css("top"), w:textWidth + padding, h:textHeight + padding, color:$p.css("color"), bgcolor:$p.css("background-color")}); 
}
```

Jquery image rotator is not displayed or loaded in IE8, opera whereas in firefox it loads and works perfect.

Comment: So what exactly is your question?

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem just in $innerText.

Comment: @leroy, you should edit your original question and add an update.  Please do not post large blocks of code into comments like that... it's impossible to read.

Answer (score 0):

why do you need "$" sign before innerText?